# Color CV vs black and white CV

Tags: cv, formatting

I see most people use a black and white academic CV. Will it be any problem
if I use a color CV like this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/4036854vqqrbp), which is mostly monochrome but uses blue in some places.

(I am applying for Graduate admission)

Comment: If you do use a color CV make sure it still looks good when printed monochrome!

Comment: @NoahSnyder this should be an answer.

Comment: I agree with @NoahSnyder. Chances are, if the CV is printed out, it will be printed out in black and white.

Comment: @dgraziotin: Ok.

Comment: @NoahSnyder how likely would a CV be printed?

Comment: Whatever you do, *dont* use coloured paper!

Comment: @Ooker, quite likely at the shortlist stage, so the interviewers have it to refer to.

Comment: @NoahSnyder if one is crafty, they can even include the CV twice in two separate layers in the PDF — one in color for screen viewing, and another in black and white for printing. Then again, that is a bit of overkill ...

Comment: @guifa what do you mean by "two separate layers"? I've not heard of such a PDF feature. Not all PDF readers support every feature, so using such wizardry is likely to cause problems. Best to keep things simple.

Comment: @Moriarty if your layers have a white background (or are exactly identical but for color), the worst case scenario would be that less advanced APIs would always show/print the top one. For how, here's a SE from 5 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524101/ I remember years ago joking around with friends sending them documents that on screen said "print me" and then have something funny print out (definitely don't do that for a CV!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The general advice is that CVs should be outstanding because of their content while their form should be relatively dull-to-boring.

The example you link to has very subtle use of color (a dark blue for headings) and is tolerable. However, you still run the risk running into faculty  with the perception that:

1. your over-designed CV is either hiding things (i.e., lack of content)
2. your over-designed CV is just a dressed up resume and that you don't understand academia at all

For those reasons, it's safest to go with a boring CV style and work on building content instead. This is generic advice for both graduate admissions as well as academic job searches.

Comment: I disagree about making it boring for the reasons you list. Design is a game of psychology with remarkable power. If you can convey the information in a more impactful way, then do it! Also, I think this must be field dependent because there are many top HCI researchers with extremely nice CVs with a lot of embellishments and images throughout.

Comment: Conversely, the bigger your name, the more latitude you have to make your cv more beautiful.

Comment: Definitely. I suppose HCI might just be an exception since a lot of grad students in the field also have CVs to match. A picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: @AustinHenley [A quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=HCI+cv&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for cv in HCI reveals to me that they are still in simple format.

Comment: @Ooker Ok, I'll be more specific: Many CVs in HCI do not follow the typical boring format.

Comment: I should note that as a faculty member on search/admission committees I do appreciate a well-laid out CV that allows me to quickly find the most relevant information (education; publications; prior positions) as quickly and efficiently as possible, without extraneous stuffing, fancy fonts, or dead white space.

Comment: A basic implementation of the `moderncv` package is hardly a case of over-design. Really, all it means is that the applicant preferred to write their CV in LaTeX rather than Word, which is a pretty common situation in STEM subjects.

Comment: Yeah, the general advice of this answer is good, but Moriarty is right that this particular example is well within the norm that no one will be distracted.

Answer (score 50):

If you do use a color CV make sure it still looks good when printed monochrome!  Some people on the committee will prefer to read hard copies, and in all likelihood they will be printed in monochrome.

Comment: It's a good general rule in academic writing to fall back gracefully when printed in monochrome -- most journals make it a (soft) requirement as well.

Comment: also often photocopied in b&w

Comment: (+1) That's true for every electronically created file that is destined for reading. Think how it would look on printed page... the even stronger test is "think how it would look after being _faxed_" (still around, these old timers).

Answer (score 13):

The content is the most important thing on a CV.

Those reading your CV will be reading many others, and you want to do everything possible to make your CV easily readable, but you also want to make it stand out.

If you can use color in a professional way that makes important stuff stand out and enhances readability, it is my opinion that you should go for it! Just make sure your colors do not stand out too much against the rest of the text. (Bright red and black on white paper doesn't look good, but black and a gray-blue theme could go well.) Some color palettes are better than others, and different palettes might go better with different fonts or layouts.

Make your design **simple** (so as to not distract from your accomplishments), **easy-to-read** (to make the document easier to skim), and **visually attractive** (to make it stand out from all the other CVs). **Choose a color that enhances these qualities.**

I would also caution against using more than one color, unless you *really* know what you're doing and/or graphic design is part of the job you are applying for.

If you choose to use color, you may want to consider how different colors may be perceived by your reader, e.g. ["Colors That Give Good First Impressions"](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/colors-that-give-good-first-impressions/).

I strongly advise *against* using color for the background of your CV (again, unless you *really* know what you're doing). This is probably too unconventional for most people and that may be seen as undesirable to your intended audience.

I suppose you *could* choose a color palette that reflects your current institution's color palette and you could include your institution's logo/seal/etc. However, this is probably a bad idea. Your CV, like a resume, is meant to advertise you, not your institution. You should not show "brand loyalty" if you are looking to leave that institution.

As mentioned in [another answer to this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/61285/32794), if you do use color, make sure it can print well.

Finally, if you *must* use more than one color, make sure it's colorblind-friendly. ["Coloring for Colorblindness"](https://davidmathlogic.com/colorblind/#%23D81B60-%231E88E5-%23FFC107-%23004D40) by David Nichols is a good resource for choosing good colors. If you have a different color scheme, you can use [the Color Blindness Simulator](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/) to help you evaluate your colors.

Answer (score 11):

The `moderncv` class is the left-justified Times New Roman of CVs in LaTeX. 
It looks good, uses color reasonably, and has well-engineered defaults, so don't worry about issues when printing in black or white.
It is a very popular package; for sure, everyone who has ever had to scan an academic CV in a scientific field has already seen a CV formatted to look exactly like yours. This isn't a bad thing in my view: it is unlikely to attract negative attention. As for attracting *positive* attention, generally you want to do that with the content of your CV, not with its unusual formatting. :)

Answer (score 4):

In my point if view, a CV with colors is for digital viewing purposes. For instance, I usually color links in my CV for a person who views it in a PDF viewer to be able to click on the links.

However, if darker colors are chosen (such as navy blue or brick red), it would not cause any problems when printed grayscale. However, if one chooses to use colors like bright green, then the links (or references) will be printed obscure.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of the replies given above. Most of the PIs use hard copies of applications while doing a video or phone interview with you and that is when they will look for specific points to frame a question for you. As such having a CV with black font is better. You can always use differences in font sizes for topics, sub-topics and text such that it becomes easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

1. Body text should always be black. At small sizes on normal printers black text will be far sharper than any other color.
2. Background should always be white.
3. Larger text doesn't have to be pure black but shuold be in dark colors that will stand up well to black and white printing and/or photocopying.

Overall the template you show doesn't look too bad but a darker blue would reduce the risk of bad copies.

Comment: I agree. The big header of each section in the CV could be in dark blue color. The detailed text inside each section should be black.  Overall, don't make your CV look like a children's color book. :-)